# killAfter deprecated warning when running exec:java

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have noticed that I get this warning every time I run my exec:java command in MAVEN.

> [WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.

How can I get rid of it? I have been searching for it, but no clue.

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foodfinder</groupId>
  <artifactId>food-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Food Finder client</name>
  <description>The client application for the Food Finder</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
        <artifactId>uimaj-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.razican.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>GitHub</system>
    <url>https://github.com/Razican/FoodClient/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>
  <ciManagement>
    <system>Travis-CI</system>
    <url>https://travis-ci.org/Razican/FoodClient</url>
  </ciManagement>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Java-Utils</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/Razican/Java-Utils/mvn-repo/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>foodfinder.client.Launcher</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>foodfinder.client.Launcher</mainClass>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the MEXEC-6 JIRA issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get rid of this warning you need to amend your pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <!--
          to get rid of the warning: [WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.
          see: method execute() in https://github.com/ispringer/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java
        -->
        <killAfter>-1</killAfter>
        <mainClass>foodfinder.client.Launcher</mainClass>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

**edit** This answer is not valid anymore for newer versions (> 1.3.2) of the `exec-maven-plugin`.

For the down-voters please have a look at the timeline.

```
Jul 2014 - release of plugin version 1.3.2
Nov 2014 - posting this answer
Mar 2015 - release of plugin version 1.4.0
```

Comment: What does that actually do, other than getting rid of the message?

Comment: @jjpe Have a look in the source search for [killAfter != -1](https://github.com/ispringer/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java#L251). If you don't need this option, it's your decission to suppress it or not. If you need this option you should leave a comment on the mentioned bug report.

Answer (score 10):

Update to version 1.4.0 of the exec-maven-plugin. The warning no longer appears.

Answer (score 3):

choose one:

1) change exec-maven-plugin configuration in your pom by adding:

```
<killAfter>-1</killAfter>
```

2) or add command-line parameter:

```
-Dexec.killAfter=-1
```